# How re-paint in Panel smooth in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, paint, paintevent

How can I repaint a panel in smooth?

I am using a timer that is invalidating the panel(`panel1.Invalidate();`) every 300ms, and then with the `panel1_Paint` event I am adding images to that panel the issue is that it looks like is jumping and I need to be moving one image on it as fast as I can.

This is a link of the screen-cast issue: `http://screencast.com/t/HdtIV99YN`

```
 private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                PaintMapObstacles(e);
                PaintMapStartAndGoal(e);

                if (trayectoryIndex < 1000)
                {
                   MapPoint point =  GetTrayectoryPoint(0, trayectoryIndex);
                   e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap("robot.jpg"), point.X*squareSize, point.Y*squareSize, 60, 60);
                   trayectoryIndex++;
               }
            }
     private void PaintMapStartAndGoal(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                MapPoint start = new MapPoint { X = 0, Y = 0 };
                MapPoint goal = new MapPoint { X = 7, Y = 8 };
                   // e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap("start.jpg"), start.X * squareSize, start.Y * squareSize, 60, 60);
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap("goal.jpg"), goal.X * squareSize, goal.Y * squareSize, 60, 60);
                    isFirstRun = true;
            }


        private void PaintMapObstacles(PaintEventArgs e)
            {

                foreach (MapPoint mpoint in obstacles.Obstacles)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap("obstacle.png"), mpoint.X * squareSize, mpoint.Y * squareSize, 60, 60);  
                }
            }

         private void PanelTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                panel1.Invalidate();
            }
```

Comment: dude, seriously, winforms is not suitable for Games (nor anything else I can think of, in 2014). If you need a framework for Games use XNA or MonoGame. Otherwise for simple board-like 2D games you can use WPF.

Comment: @HighCore you tottaly  are right. However, the big think on this project is not the simulation. I am doing AI with A* and different methods on reinforcement learning, and I don't want to spend too much time doing the visualization of the results. I know a bit of winfomrs from my past.

Comment: if you `don't want to spend to much time doing the visualization` you should really use relevant technologies. Forcing a deprecated technology into something that it is really not suitable for is going to make you lose a horrible amount of time. Not to mention the too-much-code-for-everything winforms approach per-se is already much more cumbersome than using proper DataBinding and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called "flicker", an artifact that's always around when you repaint a window from scratch.  It is especially noticeable in your program because your painting code is so inefficient.  You see the window's background getting drawn, erasing the old painting.  Then slowly getting the bitmaps drawn back onto the background.  The erasure step is visible to the eye and looks like flicker.

The general cure for flicker is double-buffering, composing the window content into a bitmap first, then quickly blitting the bitmap to the screen.  It is a built-in feature for Winforms, the DoubleBuffered property turns it on.  Double-buffering is not enabled by default for the Panel class, it was designed to be a container control that doesn't do painting on its own beyond drawing the background.   A PictureBox will work just as well in your case, it has double-buffering enabled by default.  Or you can turn on double-buffering for the Panel class, [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3113515/17034).

You do want to eventually address the problems with your painting code, beyond it being very slow, it can crash your program with an OutOfMemoryException.  A problem caused by the way you use the Bitmap class, it should be disposed after you used it.  Always use the *using* statement for System.Drawing objects.

You'll make it a lot faster by creating the bitmaps just once, the form constructor is the best place.  You make it *really* fast by prescaling the bitmaps to fit the grid and paying attention to the pixel format.  PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb is directly compatible with the frame buffer format of almost any modern video adapter, the bitmap can be directly copied into the frame buffer without conversion.  Ten times faster than all the other formats.  Conversion code [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873337/graphics-drawimage-alternatives-for-large-images/17898534#17898534).